# Execute Select Statement based on condition and user input MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to allow a particular `SELECT` statement to execute based on a particular string sent to the `IF` condition. For Example, if the user selects support from the dropdown, a variable key is sent to the sql statement, and the appropriate `SELECT` Statement is executed.

```
DECLARE @ strg
SET @strg = 'input string'
IF(SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE ticket_section = @strg)
BEGIN
SELECT
usr_users.uname AS `user`,
support_chat_user.message AS user_message,
support_chat_user.created AS user_chat_date,
support_ticket.`subject` AS ticket_subject,
support_ticket.`status` AS ticket_state,
support_ticket.created AS ticket_date,
support_ticket.modified AS updated_date,
tickets.state
FROM
tickets
INNER JOIN support_chat_user ON support_chat_user.tickets_id = tickets.tick_id
INNER JOIN support_ticket ON support_ticket.tickets_id = tickets.tick_id
INNER JOIN usr_users ON support_chat_user.reporter_id = usr_users.uid
WHERE
tickets.tick_id = '9' AND
usr_users.uid = '1'
END

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE ticket_section = @strg)

BEGIN
SELECT
usr_users.uname AS `user`,
support_chat_user.message AS user_message,
support_chat_user.created AS user_chat_date,
support_ticket.`subject` AS ticket_subject,
tickets.state
FROM
tickets
INNER JOIN support_chat_user ON support_chat_user.tickets_id = tickets.tick_id
INNER JOIN support_ticket ON support_ticket.tickets_id = tickets.tick_id
INNER JOIN usr_users ON support_chat_user.reporter_id = usr_users.uid
WHERE
tickets.tick_id = '9' AND
usr_users.uid = '1'

END
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not support `IF`, unless you put the code in a programming block.  Your question is a bit hard to follow, because the text mentions one query but the code as two that seem to be identical.

You can move the conditional logic to the outermost `WHERE` clause in your query:

```
SELECT u.uname AS `user`, scu.message AS user_message, scu.created AS user_chat_date,
       st.`subject` AS ticket_subject, st.`status` AS ticket_state, st.created AS ticket_date, st.modified AS updated_date,
       t.state
FROM tickets t JOIN
     support_chat_user scu
     ON scu.tickets_id = t.tick_id JOIN
     support_ticket st
     ON st.tickets_id = t.tick_id JOIN
     usr_users u
     ON scu.reporter_id = u.uid
WHERE t.tick_id = 9 AND  -- presumably this is not numeric
      u.uid = 1 AND      -- presumably this is not numeric
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tickets t2 WHERE t2.ticket_section = @strg)
```

I'm not sure this is what you really want.  I suspect you want:

```
WHERE t.tick_id = 9 AND  -- presumably this is not numeric
      u.uid = 1 AND      -- presumably this is not numeric
      (t.ticket_section = @strg OR @strg IS NULL)
```

However, that is merely informed speculation on what would be useful in the situation you describe.

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read (as does proper indentation).
- Numeric constants should not be introduced with single quotes.  I am guessing the ids are really numbers.  If they are strings, then single quotes are appropriate.

Comment: ,Thanks for the answer, but what i want to achieve is this, i have 3 different tables that i want query from, all these tables are linked to a central table called tickets. so if a ticket is issued by someone, it goes to the ticket table which then sub segments it to the appropriate table based on the ticket_section. so now i want to Run a query that would first check which sub table the request belongs to, then executes a particular SELECT Clause. **Note:** All the tables are not of the same structure, so different results would be achieved